# Comparing two methods to get the same array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
    np.random.seed(123456)
    X = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
    Y = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
    Z = np.random.normal(0.5, 1.7,1000)
    W = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
    stream_A = np.concatenate((X,Y,Z,W))
```

Then I am running the code below: Basically I need to create a iterator to feed one sample at a time to another function.

```
    # 4 chunks of 1000 samples, so X,Y,W and Z arrays
    n = 4 
    iter_array = iter(stream_A) # Size 4000
    result = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 1000):
        for i in range(n):
            result[i].append(next(iter_array))
```

The problem is:

`results[0]` is a list with all elements of stream X defined above.

If a compare `results[0] == X`  I get `false`

If I transform the list into np.array:

```
y=np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in result], dtype=object)
```

and then:

`y[0] == X` I also get `false`

Can someone help me why I am getting False?

And they are somehow not same because the results I am getting when I apply `X` to the function is not the same of them result when I apply `y[0]` to the same function.

Comment: Equality test for lists is different from that for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Just stack them:

```
stream_A = np.stack((X,Y,Z,W))
stream_A.shape
# (4, 1000)
np.all(stream_A[0] == X)
# True
```

Comment: Thanks for you help ! Problem is I can't use a stream with saphe(4,1000) in the iterator.  I really need to understand why they are different.

Comment: What so you mean by stream? You can just iterate over the array...